# Jest Ref event is not trigerring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks

I am using jest without enzyme, here `handleClickOutside` is not triggered at all

```
      function handleClickOutside(event: any) {
        if (
          showModal &&
          wrapperRef &&
          wrapperRef.current &&
          !wrapperRef.current.contains(event.target)
        ) {
          if (onClose) {
            onClose();
          }
        }
      }

      useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);

        return () => {
          window.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
        };
      });
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please review how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and as specific as possible with the issue you have.

Comment: so how do you renders component? and how do you trigger that `mousedown` on `window`?